# Эффект полос старого телевизора на SVG?

Tags: css3, svg, анимация, эффекты

Подскажите, как можно реализовать эффект ряби старого телевизора на SVG?

```css
.bl_svg {
  width: 60vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.st1 {
  fill: #0e1518
}

.st3 {
  fill: #fff
}

.st4 {
  fill: #f27d21;
  stroke: #0e1518;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10
}

.st5 {
  fill: #b44d26
}
```

```html
<div class="bl_svg">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 430 730">
    <g id="Television">
        <path fill="#534840" d="M34.2 466l-3.4 226 307.4 8 18.5-183.6z"/>
        <path class="st1" d="M356.7 516.4l59-72.7 10.5 193-88 63.3z"/>
        <path d="M34.8 464.7c3-1 57.8-49 57.8-49l323 28-59 72.8L34.2 466" fill="#3c3934"
              stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
        <path class="st1"
              d="M323.2 699.9l-2.7 18.4c-.3 2.2 1.3 4.2 3.5 4.4l2 .2c3.6.3 6.6-2.5 6.6-6.1v-17.9l-9.4 1zM407.9 647.4l-.4 9.2c-.2 3.5 2.5 6.5 6 6.8 3.2.3 5.9-2.3 5.8-5.5l-.6-16.8-10.8 6.3zM54.2 692.9L53 711.6c-.1 2.2 1.4 4.1 3.5 4.4 4.1.7 7.8-2.4 7.9-6.5l.3-16.9-10.7-.8"/>
        <path class="st3"
              d="M85.1 502.1c-15.9 19.5-18.8 46.3-21 71.4-2 22.6-4 45.3-6 67.9-.6 7-.9 15 4 20 2.9 3 7.1 4.4 11.1 5.5 47 13.6 96.5 18.5 145.2 14.5 11.3-.9 22.7-2.3 33.9-.9 9.3 1.2 20.2 3.9 27-2.6 3.4-3.2 4.8-8 5.9-12.5 5.7-23.2 11.2-113.4 12-119 1.4-9.9-3.6-20.2-11.6-26.3-10-7.7-23.4-9.1-36-10.2l-136.2-12.3c-9.9-.9-20.9-1.5-28.5 4.8"/>
        <path class="st1"
              d="M83.3 500.4c-17 21.3-19.6 48.9-21.9 75.1-1.4 16.2-2.9 32.3-4.3 48.5-.7 7.7-1.8 15.5-1.9 23.2-.1 5.1.7 10.6 3.9 14.8 3.9 5 10.3 6.6 16.1 8.2 7.6 2.1 15.4 4.1 23.1 5.8 15.4 3.4 31 5.8 46.8 7.4 16.1 1.6 32.3 2.3 48.5 1.9 16.1-.3 32.2-2.8 48.3-2.7 11.2 0 25.4 5.6 35.9-.3 8-4.5 9.7-14.5 11.1-22.9 2.9-17.1 4.3-34.5 5.8-51.8 1.5-17 2.7-34 4-51 .2-2.3.3-4.6.5-6.9.2-2.3.3-2.7.5-4.6.9-11.9-6.3-23.1-16.3-29.1-11.3-6.8-25.1-7.6-37.9-8.7-16.8-1.5-33.6-3-50.3-4.6-16.8-1.5-33.6-3-50.3-4.6-8.2-.7-16.5-1.5-24.7-2.2-7-.6-14.2-1.6-21.3-1-5.6.5-10.9 2.1-15.4 5.5-2.5 1.9 0 6.3 2.5 4.3 10.8-8.2 26.7-4.6 39.1-3.4 15.1 1.4 30.3 2.7 45.4 4.1 15.1 1.4 30.3 2.7 45.4 4.1 14.6 1.3 29.4 2.1 44 4.2 12.6 1.8 25.9 6.1 32.1 18.2 3.2 6.2 2.7 12.3 2.2 18.9-1.1 13.5-2 27.1-3.1 40.6-1.4 17.2-2.8 34.4-4.9 51.6-.8 6.4-1.6 12.8-2.8 19-.8 4.2-1.7 8.9-4.3 12.4-4.2 5.9-11.8 5.6-18.2 4.9-6-.7-12-1.7-18.1-1.8-7.6-.1-15.1.7-22.6 1.3-14.9 1.3-29.8 1.7-44.7 1.4-30-.7-59.8-4.8-88.8-12.2-7-1.8-17.7-2.9-22.9-8.4-4.9-5.2-3.6-13.7-3-20.2 1.5-16.8 3-33.6 4.5-50.5 2.5-28.7 2.9-61.5 21.7-85.1 1.9-2.4-1.7-5.9-3.7-3.4zM303.9 662.5c-3.3 3.1-6.1 9.4-3.4 13.6 1.4 2.3 4 3.6 6.4 4.7 3.7 1.7 7.6 3.2 11.6 3 2.8-.2 5.6-1.3 7.1-3.8.9-1.5 1.3-3.4 1.2-5.2-.1-3.3-1.3-6.6-3.1-9.3-1.5-2.4-3.5-4.5-5.9-6.1-2-1.3-5.6-3.4-8.1-2.5-1 .5-4.7 4.6-5.8 5.6zM312.3 634.8c-2.2.2-3 3.5-2.5 5.6.6 2.1 2.4 3.7 4.2 4.9.9.6 1.9 1.1 2.9 1.3 2.5.4 5-1.6 5.5-4.1.4-2.5-1-5.1-3.3-6.3M315.5 612.6c-.6.1-1.1.6-1.5 1.1-.3.5-.5 1.2-.6 1.8-.2 1.1-.5 2.2-.7 3.3-.1.5-.2 1.1-.1 1.6.2.7.8 1.3 1.5 1.5s1.5.3 2.2.3c.7 0 1.4 0 2.1-.2.7-.3 1.3-.8 1.8-1.4.7-.8 1.4-1.6 1.8-2.6.4-1 .5-2.1.1-3.1-.3-.7-.8-1.3-1.4-1.8-.9-.8-2-1.4-3.2-1.4-1.2 0-2.4.7-2.7 1.9M316.9 585.4c-.8 1.3-1.5 2.6-1.7 4.1-.2 1.5.3 3.2 1.6 3.9 1.2.7 2.7.5 4.1.3 1.2-.2 2.5-.5 3.1-1.5.5-.8.4-1.9 0-2.8s-.1-2.8-.6-3.6c-.6-.8-3.9-3.1-4.5-2.3"/>
        <g>
            <path class="st1"
                  d="M322 554.3c-1.6-.6-3.4.5-4.3 2-.8 1.5-.9 3.3-.9 5 0 .6 0 1.1.2 1.7.5 1.4 2.1 2.3 3.6 2.3s3-.6 4.4-1.2c.9-.4 1.9-.8 2.4-1.7.3-.6.4-1.3.4-2 0-1.4-.2-3-1.4-3.8-.5-.3-1.1-.5-1.7-.6-1-.2-2-2-3-2.2"/>
        </g>
    </g>

    <g id="Layer_6">
        <path d="M143.5 564.5c2.1-.1 4.2.6 5.5 2.3.7.8 1.1 1.9 1.1 2.9 0 .8-.3 1.6-.6 2.4-3 7.8-5.9 15.7-8.6 23.6-.3.7-.5 1.5-.3 2.3.6 1.9 3.4 1.6 5.3.7s4.5-1.6 5.5.1c.8 1.3-.2 3-1.3 4-3.7 3.1-9.4 3.2-12.6 6.7-1.7 1.9-2.5 4.5-3.1 6.9-1 3.6-1.9 7.3-2.9 10.9-1 3.9-2.7 8.4-6.7 9.2-.4.1-.9.1-1.3 0-1.4-.5-1.4-2.4-1.1-3.8 1.3-6.7 2.8-13.3 4.5-19.9.2-.7.3-1.4 0-2-.4-.6-1.2-.7-1.9-.8-4-.3-8 .1-11.9-.5-3.9-.6-7.9-2.6-9.6-6.2-1-2.3-1-4.9-.8-7.4.8-10.2 3.7-20 7.2-29.6 1-2.7 1.9-5.3 2.9-7.9.4-1 .8-2.1 1.2-3.1 1.3-3.5 2.5-9.2 5-12.1 2.2-2.5 7.1-4 10.2-4.8 1.6-.4 3.6-.5 4.4.8.7 1.2 0 2.8-.7 4-7.9 14.1-14.8 28.8-20.7 43.9-.9 2.4-1.8 5.3-.3 7.4.8 1.1 2.1 1.8 3.5 2.3 4.1 1.6 8.5 2.4 12.9 2.4.4 0 .9 0 1.3-.3.5-.3.6-.9.8-1.4 2.2-8.7 4.5-17.4 6.7-26.1.4-1.6.8-3.2 1.8-4.5.9-1.4 2.7-2.3 4.6-2.4zM178 551.1c3.3-1 5.6-3.9 8.8-5.2 5.8-2.5 12.9 1.1 16.1 6.6 3.2 5.5 3.3 12.2 2.6 18.6-1.6 15.7-7.5 31-16.8 43.8-2.9 3.9-6.1 7.7-10.3 10.2-4.2 2.5-9.5 3.5-14 1.7-4.1-1.6-7.1-5.3-8.7-9.3-5.2-13.3-.6-28.5 3.8-41.3 3.3-9.6 7.8-18.7 13.4-27.1 1-1.4 2.2-3 4-2.9 2.4.1 3.1 4.1.9 5 .1 0 .2 0 .2-.1zm-7.4 65.9c1.9.3 3.9-.3 6-1.6s4.3-3.5 6.5-6.6c.9-1.2 2.1-2.9 3.5-5.1 1.4-2.2 3.2-5 5.2-8.4.5-.9 1.2-2.9 2.2-6.1 1-3.2 1.6-5.4 1.8-6.7 1-7.2.6-12.8-1.2-16.7-1.8-3.9-5-6.2-9.6-6.9-.9-.1-1.9 0-3.1.3-1.2.4-2.6.9-4.1 1.8-1.6.8-2.9 1.6-3.7 2.4-.9.8-1.4 1.6-1.5 2.4 0 .8.1 1.5.1 2.1 0 .3-.3 1-.8 2.2-.5 1.2-1.2 2.8-2 4.8-.6 1.5-1.1 2.8-1.4 3.9-.3 1.2-.5 2.2-.6 3.1l-.6 6.3c-.1.5-.3 1.3-.7 2.3-.4 1-.6 1.7-.7 2.3l.3 3c0 .2 0 .6-.1 1.1s-.1 1.1-.2 1.8c-.2 1.6-.3 3.3-.3 5s.2 3.6.5 5.4c.3 2.5.9 4.4 1.6 5.7.9 1.3 1.9 2 2.9 2.2zM246.7 579.6c2.6-.4 5.4.6 6.2 3 .6 1.9-.1 4-.8 5.8-2.5 6.4-4.9 12.7-7.4 19.1-.9 2.4-1.4 6.1 1.1 6.9 1.5.5 2.9-.4 4.3-1.1 1.4-.7 3.3-1.1 4.2.2.6.8.4 1.9 0 2.8-1.8 3.5-6.6 3.6-10 5.3-4.7 2.4-6.8 8.1-7.9 13.3-1.1 5.2-2 10.8-5.5 14.8-1.5 1.6-4.6 2.5-5.4.5-.2-.6-.1-1.3 0-2 1.2-6.6 2.7-13.2 4.5-19.7.3-1 .5-2.3-.3-3-.5-.4-1.1-.5-1.7-.6-3.6-.3-7.3.1-10.9-.4s-7.3-1.8-9.4-4.8c-2.3-3.3-2.1-7.7-1.5-11.7 1.8-12.5 6.1-24.5 10.3-36.4 3.1-8.7 7-17.8 17.4-18.5 1-.1 2.1 0 2.7.8.8 1 .3 2.4-.2 3.6-6.8 14.7-16.5 28.2-21 43.8-.8 2.8-1.4 6.1.4 8.5 1.1 1.4 2.8 2.2 4.5 2.7 3.3 1.1 6.7 1.6 10.1 1.6.8 0 1.7 0 2.4-.5.9-.6 1.2-1.7 1.4-2.8 1.5-6.5 3-13.1 4.5-19.6.9-3.7 1.9-7.7 4.8-10.1.8-.8 2-1.3 3.2-1.5z"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Собственно мне как-то надо сделать чтобы текст 404 рябил, или шёл полосами.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Шум можно добавить при помощи примитива `FeTurbulence` и анимировать его. По идее шум нужно добавлять ко всему экрану, поэтому слой с надписью нужно поместить в коде перед экраном, чтобы он не был поверх эффекта.

```css
.bl_svg {
  width: 60vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.st1 {
  fill: #0e1518
}

.st3 {
  fill: gray;
}

.st4 {
  fill: #f27d21;
  stroke: #0e1518;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10
}

.st5 {
  fill: #b44d26
}
```

```html
<div class="bl_svg">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 430 730">
    <defs>
      <filter id="brokenTV">
        <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.7 0.1" numOctaves="2" seed="0" result="noise">
          <animate attributeName="baseFrequency" from="0.7 0.1" to="0.2 1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </feTurbulence>
        <feBlend in="noise" in2="BackgroundImage" mode="screen" />
      </filter>
      <clipPath id="screen">
        <path 
              d="M85.1 502.1c-15.9 19.5-18.8 46.3-21 71.4-2 22.6-4 45.3-6 67.9-.6 7-.9 15 4 20 2.9 3 7.1 4.4 11.1 5.5 47 13.6 96.5 18.5 145.2 14.5 11.3-.9 22.7-2.3 33.9-.9 9.3 1.2 20.2 3.9 27-2.6 3.4-3.2 4.8-8 5.9-12.5 5.7-23.2 11.2-113.4 12-119 1.4-9.9-3.6-20.2-11.6-26.3-10-7.7-23.4-9.1-36-10.2l-136.2-12.3c-9.9-.9-20.9-1.5-28.5 4.8"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g id="Television">
        <path fill="#534840" d="M34.2 466l-3.4 226 307.4 8 18.5-183.6z"/>
        <path class="st1" d="M356.7 516.4l59-72.7 10.5 193-88 63.3z"/>
        <path d="M34.8 464.7c3-1 57.8-49 57.8-49l323 28-59 72.8L34.2 466" fill="#3c3934"
              stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
        <path class="st1"
              d="M323.2 699.9l-2.7 18.4c-.3 2.2 1.3 4.2 3.5 4.4l2 .2c3.6.3 6.6-2.5 6.6-6.1v-17.9l-9.4 1zM407.9 647.4l-.4 9.2c-.2 3.5 2.5 6.5 6 6.8 3.2.3 5.9-2.3 5.8-5.5l-.6-16.8-10.8 6.3zM54.2 692.9L53 711.6c-.1 2.2 1.4 4.1 3.5 4.4 4.1.7 7.8-2.4 7.9-6.5l.3-16.9-10.7-.8"/>
        <g id="Layer_6">
        <path d="M143.5 564.5c2.1-.1 4.2.6 5.5 2.3.7.8 1.1 1.9 1.1 2.9 0 .8-.3 1.6-.6 2.4-3 7.8-5.9 15.7-8.6 23.6-.3.7-.5 1.5-.3 2.3.6 1.9 3.4 1.6 5.3.7s4.5-1.6 5.5.1c.8 1.3-.2 3-1.3 4-3.7 3.1-9.4 3.2-12.6 6.7-1.7 1.9-2.5 4.5-3.1 6.9-1 3.6-1.9 7.3-2.9 10.9-1 3.9-2.7 8.4-6.7 9.2-.4.1-.9.1-1.3 0-1.4-.5-1.4-2.4-1.1-3.8 1.3-6.7 2.8-13.3 4.5-19.9.2-.7.3-1.4 0-2-.4-.6-1.2-.7-1.9-.8-4-.3-8 .1-11.9-.5-3.9-.6-7.9-2.6-9.6-6.2-1-2.3-1-4.9-.8-7.4.8-10.2 3.7-20 7.2-29.6 1-2.7 1.9-5.3 2.9-7.9.4-1 .8-2.1 1.2-3.1 1.3-3.5 2.5-9.2 5-12.1 2.2-2.5 7.1-4 10.2-4.8 1.6-.4 3.6-.5 4.4.8.7 1.2 0 2.8-.7 4-7.9 14.1-14.8 28.8-20.7 43.9-.9 2.4-1.8 5.3-.3 7.4.8 1.1 2.1 1.8 3.5 2.3 4.1 1.6 8.5 2.4 12.9 2.4.4 0 .9 0 1.3-.3.5-.3.6-.9.8-1.4 2.2-8.7 4.5-17.4 6.7-26.1.4-1.6.8-3.2 1.8-4.5.9-1.4 2.7-2.3 4.6-2.4zM178 551.1c3.3-1 5.6-3.9 8.8-5.2 5.8-2.5 12.9 1.1 16.1 6.6 3.2 5.5 3.3 12.2 2.6 18.6-1.6 15.7-7.5 31-16.8 43.8-2.9 3.9-6.1 7.7-10.3 10.2-4.2 2.5-9.5 3.5-14 1.7-4.1-1.6-7.1-5.3-8.7-9.3-5.2-13.3-.6-28.5 3.8-41.3 3.3-9.6 7.8-18.7 13.4-27.1 1-1.4 2.2-3 4-2.9 2.4.1 3.1 4.1.9 5 .1 0 .2 0 .2-.1zm-7.4 65.9c1.9.3 3.9-.3 6-1.6s4.3-3.5 6.5-6.6c.9-1.2 2.1-2.9 3.5-5.1 1.4-2.2 3.2-5 5.2-8.4.5-.9 1.2-2.9 2.2-6.1 1-3.2 1.6-5.4 1.8-6.7 1-7.2.6-12.8-1.2-16.7-1.8-3.9-5-6.2-9.6-6.9-.9-.1-1.9 0-3.1.3-1.2.4-2.6.9-4.1 1.8-1.6.8-2.9 1.6-3.7 2.4-.9.8-1.4 1.6-1.5 2.4 0 .8.1 1.5.1 2.1 0 .3-.3 1-.8 2.2-.5 1.2-1.2 2.8-2 4.8-.6 1.5-1.1 2.8-1.4 3.9-.3 1.2-.5 2.2-.6 3.1l-.6 6.3c-.1.5-.3 1.3-.7 2.3-.4 1-.6 1.7-.7 2.3l.3 3c0 .2 0 .6-.1 1.1s-.1 1.1-.2 1.8c-.2 1.6-.3 3.3-.3 5s.2 3.6.5 5.4c.3 2.5.9 4.4 1.6 5.7.9 1.3 1.9 2 2.9 2.2zM246.7 579.6c2.6-.4 5.4.6 6.2 3 .6 1.9-.1 4-.8 5.8-2.5 6.4-4.9 12.7-7.4 19.1-.9 2.4-1.4 6.1 1.1 6.9 1.5.5 2.9-.4 4.3-1.1 1.4-.7 3.3-1.1 4.2.2.6.8.4 1.9 0 2.8-1.8 3.5-6.6 3.6-10 5.3-4.7 2.4-6.8 8.1-7.9 13.3-1.1 5.2-2 10.8-5.5 14.8-1.5 1.6-4.6 2.5-5.4.5-.2-.6-.1-1.3 0-2 1.2-6.6 2.7-13.2 4.5-19.7.3-1 .5-2.3-.3-3-.5-.4-1.1-.5-1.7-.6-3.6-.3-7.3.1-10.9-.4s-7.3-1.8-9.4-4.8c-2.3-3.3-2.1-7.7-1.5-11.7 1.8-12.5 6.1-24.5 10.3-36.4 3.1-8.7 7-17.8 17.4-18.5 1-.1 2.1 0 2.7.8.8 1 .3 2.4-.2 3.6-6.8 14.7-16.5 28.2-21 43.8-.8 2.8-1.4 6.1.4 8.5 1.1 1.4 2.8 2.2 4.5 2.7 3.3 1.1 6.7 1.6 10.1 1.6.8 0 1.7 0 2.4-.5.9-.6 1.2-1.7 1.4-2.8 1.5-6.5 3-13.1 4.5-19.6.9-3.7 1.9-7.7 4.8-10.1.8-.8 2-1.3 3.2-1.5z"/>
    </g>
        <path class="st3"
              d="M85.1 502.1c-15.9 19.5-18.8 46.3-21 71.4-2 22.6-4 45.3-6 67.9-.6 7-.9 15 4 20 2.9 3 7.1 4.4 11.1 5.5 47 13.6 96.5 18.5 145.2 14.5 11.3-.9 22.7-2.3 33.9-.9 9.3 1.2 20.2 3.9 27-2.6 3.4-3.2 4.8-8 5.9-12.5 5.7-23.2 11.2-113.4 12-119 1.4-9.9-3.6-20.2-11.6-26.3-10-7.7-23.4-9.1-36-10.2l-136.2-12.3c-9.9-.9-20.9-1.5-28.5 4.8"
              filter="url(#brokenTV)"
              clip-path="url(#screen) "/>
        <path class="st1"
              d="M83.3 500.4c-17 21.3-19.6 48.9-21.9 75.1-1.4 16.2-2.9 32.3-4.3 48.5-.7 7.7-1.8 15.5-1.9 23.2-.1 5.1.7 10.6 3.9 14.8 3.9 5 10.3 6.6 16.1 8.2 7.6 2.1 15.4 4.1 23.1 5.8 15.4 3.4 31 5.8 46.8 7.4 16.1 1.6 32.3 2.3 48.5 1.9 16.1-.3 32.2-2.8 48.3-2.7 11.2 0 25.4 5.6 35.9-.3 8-4.5 9.7-14.5 11.1-22.9 2.9-17.1 4.3-34.5 5.8-51.8 1.5-17 2.7-34 4-51 .2-2.3.3-4.6.5-6.9.2-2.3.3-2.7.5-4.6.9-11.9-6.3-23.1-16.3-29.1-11.3-6.8-25.1-7.6-37.9-8.7-16.8-1.5-33.6-3-50.3-4.6-16.8-1.5-33.6-3-50.3-4.6-8.2-.7-16.5-1.5-24.7-2.2-7-.6-14.2-1.6-21.3-1-5.6.5-10.9 2.1-15.4 5.5-2.5 1.9 0 6.3 2.5 4.3 10.8-8.2 26.7-4.6 39.1-3.4 15.1 1.4 30.3 2.7 45.4 4.1 15.1 1.4 30.3 2.7 45.4 4.1 14.6 1.3 29.4 2.1 44 4.2 12.6 1.8 25.9 6.1 32.1 18.2 3.2 6.2 2.7 12.3 2.2 18.9-1.1 13.5-2 27.1-3.1 40.6-1.4 17.2-2.8 34.4-4.9 51.6-.8 6.4-1.6 12.8-2.8 19-.8 4.2-1.7 8.9-4.3 12.4-4.2 5.9-11.8 5.6-18.2 4.9-6-.7-12-1.7-18.1-1.8-7.6-.1-15.1.7-22.6 1.3-14.9 1.3-29.8 1.7-44.7 1.4-30-.7-59.8-4.8-88.8-12.2-7-1.8-17.7-2.9-22.9-8.4-4.9-5.2-3.6-13.7-3-20.2 1.5-16.8 3-33.6 4.5-50.5 2.5-28.7 2.9-61.5 21.7-85.1 1.9-2.4-1.7-5.9-3.7-3.4zM303.9 662.5c-3.3 3.1-6.1 9.4-3.4 13.6 1.4 2.3 4 3.6 6.4 4.7 3.7 1.7 7.6 3.2 11.6 3 2.8-.2 5.6-1.3 7.1-3.8.9-1.5 1.3-3.4 1.2-5.2-.1-3.3-1.3-6.6-3.1-9.3-1.5-2.4-3.5-4.5-5.9-6.1-2-1.3-5.6-3.4-8.1-2.5-1 .5-4.7 4.6-5.8 5.6zM312.3 634.8c-2.2.2-3 3.5-2.5 5.6.6 2.1 2.4 3.7 4.2 4.9.9.6 1.9 1.1 2.9 1.3 2.5.4 5-1.6 5.5-4.1.4-2.5-1-5.1-3.3-6.3M315.5 612.6c-.6.1-1.1.6-1.5 1.1-.3.5-.5 1.2-.6 1.8-.2 1.1-.5 2.2-.7 3.3-.1.5-.2 1.1-.1 1.6.2.7.8 1.3 1.5 1.5s1.5.3 2.2.3c.7 0 1.4 0 2.1-.2.7-.3 1.3-.8 1.8-1.4.7-.8 1.4-1.6 1.8-2.6.4-1 .5-2.1.1-3.1-.3-.7-.8-1.3-1.4-1.8-.9-.8-2-1.4-3.2-1.4-1.2 0-2.4.7-2.7 1.9M316.9 585.4c-.8 1.3-1.5 2.6-1.7 4.1-.2 1.5.3 3.2 1.6 3.9 1.2.7 2.7.5 4.1.3 1.2-.2 2.5-.5 3.1-1.5.5-.8.4-1.9 0-2.8s-.1-2.8-.6-3.6c-.6-.8-3.9-3.1-4.5-2.3"/>
        <g>
            <path class="st1"
                  d="M322 554.3c-1.6-.6-3.4.5-4.3 2-.8 1.5-.9 3.3-.9 5 0 .6 0 1.1.2 1.7.5 1.4 2.1 2.3 3.6 2.3s3-.6 4.4-1.2c.9-.4 1.9-.8 2.4-1.7.3-.6.4-1.3.4-2 0-1.4-.2-3-1.4-3.8-.5-.3-1.1-.5-1.7-.6-1-.2-2-2-3-2.2"/>
        </g>
    </g>

    
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Интересно вышло. Спасибо. А как допустим повысить зернистость ряби ?

Comment: Не за что. Зернистость задаётся атрибутом  `baseFrequency`. Чтобы зернистость увеличить - значение атрибута надо уменьшить. Например, анимировать не между 0.7 и 1.4 , а  0.6 и 0.8 . Также в значение атрибута можно ввести два числа: для горизонтали и вертикали.

Comment: В Firefox не работает

Comment: @andreymal , в firefox не все примитивы svg-фильтрв работают. Тут уж в формате `svg` вряд-ли можно что-нибудь сделать. Надо или gif-ку или на `canvas`-е рисовать.